# Change Windows Live ID Without Resetting The Phone [ROOT]

Tags: microsoft-account, 7.8, reset

My phone is rooted  HTC HD7 running WP 7.8 and I have an app called `WP7 Root Tools By HeathCliff74` which gives me a `File Explorer` and `Registry Browser` and I want to change the Windows Live ID on my phone without resetting my phone because I'm giving my phone away to a family and I have lots of useful apps etc. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I also should note that I'm concerned about losing my root after a hard reset, that's what will hold me back from resetting the phone.